Why is this non $\Gamma$-factor, $K(s)$ so accurate? $ \Psi(s):=K(s)\zeta(s)$
Define $$ \Psi(s):=K(s)\zeta(s)$$
where $K(s)=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{s}}K_1(1.35\sqrt{s})$, where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel of the second kind. Note that:
$$\Psi(s)\approx\Psi(1-s) \tag{1}$$

Is there a reason for this $K(s)$ factor making $(1)$ nearly an equality? Is there any utility for this or is it just a coincidence?

For example if we had the usual $\Gamma$-factor with
$$\hat\zeta(s):=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$$
then we get exactly $$ \hat \zeta(s)=\hat \zeta(1-s) $$
Here's a link to a plot involving $\Psi(s)$ and $\Psi(1-s)$ on the same plot.

What does “accurate” mean precisely? Is it the approximation (1) that's surprisingly accurate, or something having to do with $\zeta(s)$?

@GregMartin Yes the factor $K(s)$ makes $(1)$ close to an equality
